# Can't install or upgrade any package

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

When running `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-all : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 git : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 icecast2 : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 libquvi7 : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 libraptor2-0 : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 python-pycurl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.24.0) but it is not installed
 transmission-gtk : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 vorbis-tools : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2-1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I run `apt-get -f install` I get:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libebml3:amd64': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

So I'm running `dpkg --configure -a` but I get:

```
Setting up libfreetype6:amd64 (2.4.9-1.1+deb7u7) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libfreetype6:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libxml2:amd64 (2.8.0+dfsg1-7+wheezy7) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libxml2:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.1t-1+deb7u2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libperl5.14 (5.14.2-21+deb7u5) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libperl5.14 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libffi5:amd64 (3.0.10-3+deb7u2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libffi5:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcairo2:amd64:
 libcairo2:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.3.5); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libcairo2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libupnp6 (1:1.6.17-1.2+deb7u2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libupnp6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libgcrypt11:amd64 (1.5.0-5+deb7u5) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libgcrypt11:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icecast2:
 icecast2 depends on libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3-gnutls is not installed.
 icecast2 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing icecast2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbind9-80:
 libbind9-80 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.6.27); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libbind9-80 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgd2-xpm:amd64:
 libgd2-xpm:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgd2-xpm:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libtasn1-3:amd64 (2.13-2+deb7u4) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libtasn1-3:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpijs:
 printer-driver-hpijs depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-hpijs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dnsutils:
 dnsutils depends on libbind9-80 (= 1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u16); however:
  Package libbind9-80 is not configured yet.
 dnsutils depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 dnsutils depends on libxml2 (>= 2.6.27); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing dnsutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hpijs:
 hpijs depends on printer-driver-hpijs; however:
  Package printer-driver-hpijs is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing hpijs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libxapian22 (1.2.12-2+deb7u1) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libxapian22 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:3.6.6-6+deb7u13) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libwbclient0:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-3-0:amd64:
 libgail-3-0:amd64 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.10.0); however:
  Package libcairo2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgail-3-0:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgail-3-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssl:
 openssl depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1e-2+deb7u20); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing openssl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpcups:
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-hpcups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxslt1.1:amd64:
 libxslt1.1:amd64 depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Package libgcrypt11:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libxslt1.1:amd64 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libxslt1.1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisc84:
 libisc84 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libisc84 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore5-extra:amd64:
 libmagickcore5-extra:amd64 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.6.0); however:
  Package libcairo2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore5-extra:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore5-extra:amd64 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libmagickcore5-extra:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rtmpdump:
 rtmpdump depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Package libgcrypt11:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing rtmpdump (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-common:
 grub-common depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing grub-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libgif4 (4.1.6-10+deb7u1) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libgif4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libisccfg82:
 libisccfg82 depends on libisc84; however:
  Package libisc84 is not configured yet.
 libisccfg82 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.6.27); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libisccfg82 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libmagic1:amd64 (5.11-2+deb7u9) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libmagic1:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ntfs-3g:
 ntfs-3g depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Package libgcrypt11:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ntfs-3g (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfontconfig1:amd64:
 libfontconfig1:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libfontconfig1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 1.99-27+deb7u3); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickwand5:amd64:
 libmagickwand5:amd64 depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
  Package libfontconfig1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickwand5:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libmagickwand5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgimp2.0:
 libgimp2.0 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.10.2); however:
  Package libcairo2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgimp2.0 depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
  Package libfontconfig1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgimp2.0 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgimp2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64 (0.10.36-1.1+deb7u2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up libslp1 (1.2.1-9+deb7u1) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libslp1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of file:
 file depends on libmagic1 (= 5.11-2+deb7u9); however:
  Package libmagic1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing file (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgsf-1-114:
 libgsf-1-114 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgsf-1-114 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.13-38+deb7u12) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing libc6-i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Setting up liblcms2-2:amd64 (2.2+git20110628-2.2+deb7u2) ...
Bus error
dpkg: error processing liblcms2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cgi:
 php5-cgi depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 php5-cgi depends on libxml2 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package libxml2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 php5-cgi depends on libmagic1; however:
  Package libmagic1:amd64 is not configured yet

.
.
.
..
...
many lines skiped
...
..
.
.
.


dpkg: error processing php5-curl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtiff-tools:
 libtiff-tools depends on libtiff5 (>> 4.0.0-1~); however:
  Package libtiff5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libtiff-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxi6:amd64:
 libxi6:amd64 depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1); however:
  Package libx11-6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libxi6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exiv2:
 exiv2 depends on libexiv2-12; however:
  Package libexiv2-12 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing exiv2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libswscale2:amd64:
 libswscale2:amd64 depends on libavutil51 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~); however:
  Package libavutil51:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libswscale2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libavdevice53:amd64:
 libavdevice53:amd64 depends on libavcodec53 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~) | libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 6:0.8.20); however:
  Package libavcodec53:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libavcodec-extra-53 is not installed.
 libavdevice53:amd64 depends on libavformat53 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~); however:
  Package libavformat53:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libavdevice53:amd64 depends on libavutil51 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~); however:
  Package libavutil51:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libavdevice53:amd64 depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1); however:
  Package libx11-6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libavdevice53:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lynx:
 lynx depends on lynx-cur (>= 2.8.8dev.12-2+deb7u1); however:
  Package lynx-cur is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing lynx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-mpm-prefork:
 apache2-mpm-prefork depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
 apache2-mpm-prefork depends on apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8); however:
  Package apache2.2-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing apache2-mpm-prefork (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxfixes3:amd64:
 libxfixes3:amd64 depends on libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1); however:
  Package libx11-6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libxfixes3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss3-1d:amd64:
 libnss3-1d:amd64 depends on libnss3 (= 2:3.26-1+debu7u4); however:
  Package libnss3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libnss3-1d:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-postscript-hp:
 printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on hplip (>= 3.12.6-3.1+deb7u2); however:
  Package hplip is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up texlive-latex-base-doc (2012.20120611-5+deb7u1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2:
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not configured yet.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u8); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing apache2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of exim4:
 exim4 depends on exim4-daemon-light | exim4-daemon-heavy | exim4-daemon-custom; however:
  Package exim4-daemon-light is not configured yet.
  Package exim4-daemon-heavy is not installed.
  Package exim4-daemon-custom is not installed.

dpkg: error processing exim4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zendframework:
 zendframework depends on php5 | php5-cli; however:
  Package php5 is not configured yet.
  Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing zendframework (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-imgproc2.3:
 libopencv-imgproc2.3 depends on libopencv-core2.3 (= 2.3.1-11+deb7u1); however:
  Package libopencv-core2.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libopencv-imgproc2.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sane-utils:
 sane-utils depends on libsane (>= 1.0.11-3); however:
  Package libsane:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing sane-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython2.7:
 libpython2.7 depends on python2.7 (= 2.7.3-6+deb7u3); however:
  Package python2.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libpython2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Setting up texlive-latex-base (2012.20120611-5+deb7u1) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Building format(s) --all --cnffile /etc/texmf/fmt.d/10texlive-latex-base.cnf.
        This may take some time... done.
Setting up texlive-metapost (2012.20120611-5+deb7u1) ...
Setting up texlive-luatex (2012.20120611-5+deb7u1) ...
Processing triggers for tex-common ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Setting up perl-modules (5.14.2-21+deb7u5) ...
Setting up perl (5.14.2-21+deb7u5) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.16.18) ...
Setting up libsoap-lite-perl (0.714-1+deb7u1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/usb-common.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/usb-common.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-jumpshot.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-jumpshot.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-karma.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-karma.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-cypress.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-cypress.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-realtek.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-realtek.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-eneub6250.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-eneub6250.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-sddr09.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-sddr09.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-datafab.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-datafab.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-sddr55.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-sddr55.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-alauda.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-alauda.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-isd200.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-isd200.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-onetouch.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-onetouch.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-freecom.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-freecom.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
install: reading `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-usbat.ko': Input/output error
install: failed to extend `/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_k0lCUc//lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/ums-usbat.ko': Input/output error
Bus error
depmod: ../libkmod/libkmod-elf.c:207: elf_get_mem: Assertion `offset < elf->size' failed.
Aborted
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfreetype6:amd64
 libxml2:amd64
 libssl1.0.0:amd64
 libperl5.14
 libffi5:amd64
 libcairo2:amd64
 libupnp6
 libgcrypt11:amd64
 icecast2
 libbind9-80
 libgd2-xpm:amd64
 libtasn1-3:amd64
 printer-driver-hpijs
 dnsutils
 hpijs
 libxapian22
 libwbclient0:amd64
 libgail-3-0:amd64
 openssl
 printer-driver-hpcups
 libxslt1.1:amd64
 libisc84
 libmagickcore5-extra:amd64
 rtmpdump
 grub-common
 libgif4
 libisccfg82
 libmagic1:amd64
 ntfs-3g
 libfontconfig1:amd64
 grub-pc-bin
 libmagickwand5:amd64
 libgimp2.0
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64
 libslp1
 file
 libgsf-1-114
 libc6-i386
 liblcms2-2:amd64
 php5-cgi
 libwmf0.2-7:amd64
 libebml3:amd64
 php5-gd
 libsmbclient:amd64
 libmagick++5:amd64
 libcairo-gobject2:amd64
 libsqlite3-0:amd64
 libgtk-3-0:amd64
 libnspr4:amd64
 libexpat1:amd64
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:amd64
 libarchive12:amd64
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64
 libass4:amd64
 liblwres80
 libidn11:amd64
 libxml2-utils
 python2.7-minimal
 ntfsprogs
 libtiff5:amd64
 libtiff4:amd64
 librtmp0:amd64
 libaudiofile1:amd64
 libsystemd-login0:amd64
 libgs9
 libkrb5support0:amd64
 wget
 bind9-host
 libgme0
 librsvg2-2:amd64
 libpoppler-glib8:amd64
 ntp
 debootstrap
 libsndfile1:amd64
 libmpg123-0:amd64
 libhpmud0
 nginx-full
 libcurl3:amd64
 nginx
 libimlib2
 libminiupnpc5
 librsvg2-common:amd64
 openvpn
 apache2-utils
 libc6-dev-i386
 libtidy-0.99-0
 libx11-6:amd64
 libgtk-3-bin
 libjasper1:amd64
 openssh-server
 openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64
 libavfilter2:amd64
 libcroco3:amd64
 libplist1
 libgnutls26:amd64
 xsltproc
 poppler-utils
 grub-pc
 openjdk-6-jre:amd64
 openjdk-6-jre-lib
 libavutil51:amd64
 python-magic
 samba-common-bin
 ghostscript
 libx11-dev:amd64
 liblcms1:amd64
 libc-ares2:amd64
 xscreensaver
 git
 monit
 libmp3lame0:amd64
 mpg123
 libjbig2dec0
 libx11-xcb1:amd64
 libavformat53:amd64
 apache2.2-common
 python-imaging
 libexiv2-12
 php5-cli
 libapache2-mod-php5
 apache2.2-bin
 libldap-2.4-2:amd64
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64
 libnss3:amd64
 libicu48:amd64
 imagemagick
 libxtst6:amd64
 libpostproc52:amd64
 libnspr4-0d:amd64
 libisccc80
 python-libxml2
 libnettle4:amd64
 lynx-cur
 openssh-client
 libevent-2.0-5:amd64
 ntpdate
 ghostscript-cups
 php5
 grub2-common
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64
 libpng12-0:amd64
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
 libdns88
 libpixman-1-0:amd64
 libpoppler19:amd64
 lame
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64
 libonig2
 gstreamer0.10-x:amd64
 libopencv-core2.3
 hplip
 libpcsclite1:amd64
 binutils
 gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64
 libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0:amd64
 libkrb5-3:amd64
 libssh2-1:amd64
 gimp
 libmagickcore5:amd64
 suckless-tools
 libpq5
 libsane-hpaio
 libsane:amd64
 xscreensaver-data
 libavcodec53:amd64
 fontconfig
 libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64
 php5-pgsql
 libav-tools
 ssl-cert
 dpkg-dev
 libmatroska5:amd64
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64
 libmp3lame-dev:amd64
 libk5crypto3:amd64
 libxrender1:amd64
 openjdk-6-jdk:amd64
 libxvmc1
 libxpm4:amd64
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 ffmpeg
 libxrandr2:amd64
 exim4-daemon-light
 python2.7
 libxv1:amd64
 curl
 php-pear
 php5-curl
 libtiff-tools
 libxi6:amd64
 exiv2
 libswscale2:amd64
 libavdevice53:amd64
 lynx
 apache2-mpm-prefork
 libxfixes3:amd64
 libnss3-1d:amd64
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 apache2
 exim4
 zendframework
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0
 libopencv-imgproc2.3
 sane-utils
 libpython2.7
```

I've done a lot of research but I cannot fix this.

---

I am using ssh so I can't use Synaptic manager. `sudo apt-get check` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 conky-all : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 git : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 icecast2 : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 libquvi7 : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 libraptor2-0 : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 python-pycurl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.24.0) but it is not installed
 transmission-gtk : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installed
 vorbis-tools : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2-1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Also I can't install `gedit` because it returns the same error as above.

Comment: First of all, start by running `sudo apt-get update` to update package database. Then run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and update your questions withthe outputifthereare any errors.

Comment: yeah, i forgot to mention this. I had already run `sudo apt-get update` before running the above

Comment: See the part of the initial error message that says `Input/Output` error? Bad news - sometimes indicating hardware failure. Look up how to run a SMART test on your HDD to rule out hardware failure. If your disk tests good, then try installing libcurl3-gnutls again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet)

Comment: My problem (similar to yours) was solved after following Soren's advice. In particular, remember to also run `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 5):

Try opening Synaptic manager and check for broken packages and remove them if any.
Also, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

If the lost dependencies error resume, you can try this:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then you can delete the depends packages by search and delete.

---

**Update after your comment:**

To fix the broken dependencies without using Synaptic manager issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If the problem resumes, you can try the above command by editing status  file manually, and because you use ssh, try different non-graphical editors like `nano` or `vim` or any other.
Try this:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then remove the whole block of information belonging to each broken package.

Comment: i am using ssh so i cant use synaptic manager. `sudo apt-get check` returns too many lines so i posted a reply

Comment: @geprge n , did you try to install these missing packages ? and tell me if you tried to run 32 architecture packages or not

Comment: @george please review the answer again , i have update it after your comment

Comment: It seems the double dash was lost in your anwer for --configure and --fix-missing , can you fix it so people can copy / paste the commands

Comment: @blackjack75 You could have [suggested the edit](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing) yourself (and gained 2 [reputation points](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation)…)