# I'm getting an error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: package-management, dpkg, phpmyadmin

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I was having a `dpkg` error so I searched online for solutions and I ran `sudo apt install -f` and it returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up javascript-common (11+nmu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
 installed javascript-common package post-installation script subprocess returne
d error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libjs-popper.js:
 libjs-popper.js depends on javascript-common; however:
  Package javascript-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libjs-popper.js (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libjs-bootstrap4:
 libjs-bootstrap4 depends on libjs-popper.js (>= 1.14.6+ds2-2); however:
  Package libjs-popper.js is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libjs-bootstrap4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of phpmyadmin:
 phpmyadmin depends on libjs-bootstrap4; however:
  Package libjs-bootstrap4 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written bec
ause MaxReports is reached already
                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 javascript-common
 libjs-popper.js
 libjs-bootstrap4
 phpmyadmin
```

Then I tried running `sudo apt install --fix-broken` which also returned similar errors.

I've started using Ubuntu very recently and this error is really bothersome. It will be really helpful if you could suggest some fix.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/)

Comment: @WakilAhmed In your post you had asked two questions. I removed one of them so that the question won't be closed as needing more focus. Also you have received answers regarding only the first of the two questions. If you still need help with the other question, please as a new question about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just ran these commands.

```
sudo apt remove libjs-popper.js
sudo apt remove javascript-common
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge javascript-common
sudo apt-get remove --purge libjs-popper.js
sudo apt-get remove --purge libjs-bootstrap4
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin
sudo apt autoremove --purge phpmyadmin dbconfig-common
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update
```