# No GUI or display after install the nvidia driver 535 onto Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to install the nvidia driver 535 onto my new laptop with Ubuntu20.04, the installation went well. But I couldn’t get to the GUI display after reboot. There’s only a short small dash flashing in the upper left corner of the screen.
I’ve tried to reinstall, failed. Reconfigure, failed as well. Every methods I can search for have been tried and failed. The only thing left is staring at the tty page.

What can I do next to fix it, I am really anxious and confused about that. Much thanks!

Btw: Dell OMEN9slim, Ubuntu20.04, nvidia driver 535.86.05

21,Jul:
referring to the comment, I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu to 22.04 and reinstall the desktop. it exactly show the display, but some other errors occur this time when I try to reinstall the driver535.

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-76-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.54.03/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-535 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-535 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up libnvidia-decode-535:amd64 (535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535 (535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-535:
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (<= 535.54.03-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (>= 535.54.03); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-535 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libx11-6:i386 (2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up libnvidia-encode-535:amd64 (535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-535:i386 (535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-535:i386 (535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-535:i386 (535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-76-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p8
I: (UUID=3fc2a239-f279-4907-9378-0f5f513261d3)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-535
 nvidia-driver-535
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: If that machine is the 13th gen i9 with a RTX4090, try a later release, like 22.04 or 23.04. Even the alpha release of 23.10 might work if those fail.

Comment: referring to the comment, I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu to 22.04 and reinstall the desktop. it exactly show the display, but some other errors occur this time. 
‘’’

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/)