# Ubuntu 22.04 - nvidia 525 driver not compatible with 6.0 kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 22.04

I am using an eGPU with my laptop and looking to setup the appropriate nvidia drivers.

Relevant specs:

- Razer X Chroma eGPU enclosure
- RTX 3070 Ti
- Ubuntu 22.04
- kernel:  6.0.0-060000-generic

When attempting to install nvidia-driver-535 (not server or open) from the additional drivers section, I get the following error:

```
pk-client-error-quark: Error while installing package: installed nvidia-dkms-535 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10 (313)
```

When attempting to fix things with `update` and `upgrade`, I then get the following error:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.0.0-060000-generic is not su
pported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.0-060000-generic (x86_6
4)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.54.03/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-535 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-535 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-535:
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (<= 535.54.03-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (>= 535.54.03); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-535 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13
.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-060000-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-535
 nvidia-driver-535
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

which from my limited understanding there is some compatibility issue with my current kernel. I've heard that downgrading my kernel can cause instability issues, so I would prefer to make it work with my current kernel if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/)