# Fail to start redis-server as system service

Tags: redis

I uninstall redis and reinstall it on my ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Got this error in `sudo apt-get install redis`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  redis-server redis-tools
Suggested packages:
  ruby-redis
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  redis redis-server redis-tools
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,432 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,277 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package redis-tools.
(Reading database ... 250491 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../redis-tools_6%3a7.2.1-1rl1~focal1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking redis-tools (6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package redis-server.
Preparing to unpack .../redis-server_6%3a7.2.1-1rl1~focal1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking redis-server (6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package redis.
Preparing to unpack .../redis_6%3a7.2.1-1rl1~focal1_all.deb ...
Unpacking redis (6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1) ...
Setting up redis-tools (6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1) ...
Setting up redis-server (6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1) ...
Job for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis-server.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-16 13:00:20 PDT; 5ms ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 2419910 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2419910 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Redis is loading..."
dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
 installed redis-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of redis:
 redis depends on redis-server (<< 6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1.1~); however:
  Package redis-server is not configured yet.
 redis depends on redis-server (>= 6:7.2.1-1rl1~focal1); however:
  Package redis-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package redis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.22) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redis-server
 redis
```

This is what `sudo systemctl status redis-server` returns

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis-server.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-16 13:02:44 PDT; 6min ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 2422809 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2422809 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Redis is loading..."

Oct 16 13:02:44 VAN-904647-PC1 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 16 13:02:44 VAN-904647-PC1 systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced key-value store.
Oct 16 13:02:44 VAN-904647-PC1 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 16 13:02:44 VAN-904647-PC1 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 13:02:44 VAN-904647-PC1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

I can start redis-server in cli though. This error will always show up when I try to use `apt install`. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/)