# Cannot install Canon Pixma ip100 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing

I've downloaded:

cnijfilter-ip100series-3.70-1-deb.tar.gz
  cnijfilter-ip100series-3.70-1-rpm.tar.gz
  cnijfilter-source-3.70-1.tar.gz

I tried following the installation instructions from Canon, but it failed. I continued to try answers given in ask Ubuntu where the only one that actually started driver installations is: `./install.sh`

Unfortunately I'm stuck with several errors according to below.

```
./install.sh
[sudo] password for thomas: 
==================================================

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver
Version 3.70
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2012
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-common_3.70-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-common.
(Reading database ... 204048 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-common_3.70-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnijfilter-common (3.70-1) ...
Setting up cnijfilter-common (3.70-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.5) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-ip100series_3.70-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-ip100series.
(Reading database ... 204065 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-ip100series_3.70-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnijfilter-ip100series (3.70-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-ip100series:
 cnijfilter-ip100series depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.12.3); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-ip100series depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.8rel); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-ip100series depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-ip100series (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnijfilter-ip100series
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-ip100series
(Reading database ... 204273 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-ip100series (3.70-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-ip100series (3.70-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.5) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-common
(Reading database ... 204065 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-common (3.70-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-common (3.70-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.5) ...
```

Comment: "however: Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed." Did you try installing this and all of the missing dependencies; e.g.`sudo apt update && sudo apt install libpango1.0-0` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet)

Comment: Thanks but still stucked... 

Using the command "sudo apt update && sudo apt install libpango1.0-0"   rr:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu jammy Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done                            
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.